# send Synchronous request using ASIHTTPREQUEST libraries showing activity indicator in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, asynchronous, uiactivityindicatorview

I want to show activity indicator while sending and receiving synchronous asihttprequest from server.  I have used activity indicator as the asihttprequest is send but it did not showing in iPhone due to synchronous request.
Any suggestion how to show activity indicator during synchronous data transfer.
Thanks

Comment: Please note, that ASIHTTPRequest is not actively developed anymore: http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchronous request calls your activity indicator delegate method `setProgress:` on the main thread.

B/c you are using `ASIHTTPRequest` on the main thread you are blocking the UI, hence calls to `setProgress`: are queuing to be dispatched after the request is finished, but by that time the progress is already 100%

To solve this use either asynchronous request or call synchronous request on a background thread using

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startSynchronous:) withObject:nil];
```

**Edit**

Remember to create your own autorelease pool to handle the memory inside your startSynchronous: method

```
-(void)startSynchronous:(BOOL)animate{
       NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

       NSString *autoreleasedString = @"xxx";   

       NSLog(@"%@",autoreleasedString);

       [pool drain];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, using your line of code solves my problem but in console window it showing '*** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x6396660 of class NSConcreteMutableData autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking'. Cam you explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: When you call a function to be executed in other thread then Main thread you will need to take care of the autorreleasing objects your self. I will edit the code to show it.